# Calling an ADFS secured Web Api from a Desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, adfs3.0

I have a Web Api that I have secured with ADFS.  When I call the Web Api through a browser, it gets redirected to the ADFS where I am prompted for username and password.  After entering the credentials, I get redirected back to the Web Api and I get the expected results.

When I try to call the Web Api from a desktop application, instead of getting the expected results, I get a text/html response of what looks like the adfs login prompt page.

I've looked through stackoverflow and other sources but I still haven't been able to solve this issue.  Any help is appreciated.

I've primarily used

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2017/05/10/adal-secure-web-api-with-adfs-3-0-for-desktop-client/

and

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/

while trying to figure this out yet I can't see what I've done wrong.

Values Controller on the webapi

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Test")]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetTestData()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

My Desktop Application code

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string authority = "https://devadfs/adfs/ls/";
    string resourceURI = "https://mywebapi";
    string clientID = "09c9a8a2-6bf1-427d-89ba-45c2c02bb9fc";
    string clientReturnURI = "https://mywebapi";

    string authHeader = await GetAuthorizationHeader(authority, resourceURI, clientID, clientReturnURI);

    string responseString = await CallService(resourceURI, authHeader);

    if (responseString.Length > 2000) responseString = responseString.Substring(0, 2000);
    MessageBox.Show(responseString);
}

private static async Task<string> CallService(string resourceURI, string authHeader)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, resourceURI + "/api/Values/Test");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return responseString;
}

private static async Task<string> GetAuthorizationHeader(string authority, string resourceURI, string clientID, string clientReturnURI)
{
    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false); //initialize authority to point to adfs
    AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI, clientID, new Uri(clientReturnURI), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)); // obtain token for the resource
    string authHeader = ar.CreateAuthorizationHeader();

    return authHeader;
}
```

The Result of the Web Api from the browser

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>value1</string>
<string>value2</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

The Result of the Web Api from the Desktop Application

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10.000"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache,no-store"/>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1"/>
        <meta name='mswebdialog-title' content='Connecting to devadfs'/>

        <title>Sign In</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function LoginErrors(){this.userNameFormatError = 'Enter your user ID in the format \u0026quot;domain\\user\u0026quot; or \u0026quot;user@domain\u0026quot;.'; this.passwordEmpty = 'Enter your password.'; this.passwordTooLong = 'Password must be shorter than 128 characters.';}; var maxPasswordLength = 128;
//]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
function InputUtil(errTextElementID, errDisplayElementID) {

    if (!errTextElementID)  errTextElementID = 'errorText'; 
    if (!errDisplayElementID)  errDisplayElementID = 'error'; 

    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.errLabel = document.getElementById(errTextElementID);
    this.errDisplay = document.getElementById(errDisplayElementID);
};
InputUtil.prototype.canDisplayError = function () {
    return this.errLabel && this.errDisplay;
}
InputUtil.prototype.checkError = function () {
    if (!this.canDisplayError){
        throw new Error ('Error element not present');
    }
    if (this.errLabel && this.errLabel.innerHTML) {
        this.errDisplay.style.display = '';        
        var cause = this.errLabel.getAttribute('for');
        if (cause) {
            var causeNode = document.getElementById(cause);
            if (causeNode && causeNode.value) {
                causeNode.focus();
                this.hasFocus = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        this.errDisplay.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
InputUtil.prototype.setInitialFocus = function (input) {
    if (this.hasFocus) return;
    var node = document.getElementById(input);
    if (node) {
        if ((/^\s*$/).test(node.value)) {
            node.focus();
            this.hasFocus = true;
        }
    }
};
InputUtil.prototype.setError = function (input, errorMsg) {
    if (!this.canDisplayError) {
        throw new Error('Error element not present');
    }
    input.focus();

    if (errorMsg) {
        this.errLabel.innerHTML = errorMsg;
    }
    this.errLabel.setAttribute('for', input.id);
    this.errDisplay.style.display = '';
};
InputUtil.makePlaceholder = function (input) {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;

    if (ua != null && 
        (ua.match(/MSIE 9.0/) != null || 
         ua.match(/MSIE 8.0/) != null ||
         ua.match(/MSIE 7.0/) != null)) {
        var node = document.getElementById(input);
        if (node) {
            var placeholder = node.getAttribute("placeholder");
            if (placeholder != null && placeholder != '') {
                var label = document.createElement('input');
                label.type = "text";
                label.value = placeholder;
                label.readOnly = true;
                label.style.position = 'absolute';
                label.style.borderColor = 'transparent';
                label.className = node.className + ' hint';
                label.tabIndex = -1;
                label.onfocus = function () { this.nextSibling.focus(); };

                node.style.position = 'relative';
                node.parentNode.style.position = 'relative';
                node.parentNode.insertBefore(label, node);
                node.onkeyup = function () { InputUtil.showHint(this); };
                node.onblur = function () { InputUtil.showHint(this); };
                node.style.background = 'transparent';

                node.setAttribute("placeholder", "");
                InputUtil.showHint(node);
            }
        }
    }
};
InputUtil.focus = function (inputField) {
    var node = document.getElementById(inputField);
    if (node) node.focus();
};
InputUtil.hasClass = function(node, clsName) {
    return node.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + clsName + '(\\s|$)'));
};
InputUtil.addClass = function(node, clsName) {
    if (!this.hasClass(node, clsName)) node.className += " " + clsName;
};
InputUtil.removeClass = function(node, clsName) {
    if (this.hasClass(node, clsName)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + clsName + '(\\s|$)');
        node.className = node.className.replace(reg, ' ');
    }
};
InputUtil.showHint = function (node, gotFocus) {
    if (node.value && node.value != '') {
        node.previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        node.previousSibling.style.display = '';
    }
};
//]]>
</script>



        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/adfs/portal/css/style.css?id=D74D4D6943F32AE6F7F11D14D601DBB0E1A58919176EE512150366B6279AAF99" /><style>.illustrationClass {background-image:url(/adfs/portal/illustration/illustration.png?id=183128A3C941EDE3D9199FA37D6AA90E0A7DFE101B37D10B4FEDA0CF35E11AFD);}</style>

    </head>
    <body dir="ltr" class="body">
    <div id="noScript" style="position:static; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:100">
        <h1>JavaScript required</h1>
        <p>JavaScript is required. This web browser does not support JavaScript or JavaScript in this web browser is not enabled.</p>
        <p>To find out if your web browser supports JavaScript or to enable JavaScript, see web browser help.</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
         document.getElementById("noScript").style.display = "none";
    </script>
    <div id="fullPage">
        <div id="brandingWrapper" class="float">
            <div id="branding"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentWrapper" class="float">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="header">
                    devadfs
                </div>
                <div id="workArea">

    <div id="authArea" class="groupMargin">


    <div id="loginArea">        
        <div id="loginMessage" class="groupMargin">Sign in with your organizational account</div>

        <form method="post" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate" onKeyPress="if (event && event.keyCode == 13) Login.submitLoginRequest();" action="/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fmywebapi%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252fapi%252fValues%252fTest&wct=2018-09-07T12%3a50%3a02Z" >
            <div id="error" class="fieldMargin error smallText">
                <label id="errorText" for=""></label>
            </div>

            <div id="formsAuthenticationArea">
                <div id="userNameArea">
                    <input id="userNameInput" name="UserName" type="email" value="" tabindex="1" class="text fullWidth" 
                        spellcheck="false" placeholder="someone@example.com" autocomplete="off"/>     
                </div>

                <div id="passwordArea">
                     <input id="passwordInput" name="Password" type="password" tabindex="2" class="text fullWidth" 
                        placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"/>                                   
                </div>
                <div id="kmsiArea" style="display:none">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Kmsi" id="kmsiInput" value="true" tabindex="3" />
                    <label for="kmsiInput">Keep me signed in</label>
                </div>
                <div id="submissionArea" class="submitMargin">
                    <span id="submitButton" class="submit" tabindex="4" 
                        onKeyPress="if (event && event.keyCode == 32) Login.submitLoginRequest();" 
                        onclick="return Login.submitLoginRequest();">Sign in</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input id="optionForms" type="hidden" name="AuthMethod" value="FormsAuthentication"/>
        </form>

             <div id="authOptions">
        <form id="options"  method="post" action="https://devadfs/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fmywebapi%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252fapi%252fValues%252fTest&wct=2018-09-07T12%3a50%3a02Z">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function SelectOption(option) {
                    var i = document.getElementById('optionSelection');
                    i.value = option;
                    document.forms['options'].submit();
                    return false;
                }
            </script>
            <input id="optionSelection" type="hidden" name="AuthMethod" />
            <div class='groupMargin'></div>
        </form>
      </div>

        <div id="introduction" class="groupMargin">

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

            function Login() {
            }

            Login.userNameInput = 'userNameInput';
            Login.passwordInput = 'passwordInput';

            Login.initialize = function () {

                var u = new InputUtil();

                u.checkError();
                u.setInitialFocus(Login.userNameInput);
                u.setInitialFocus(Login.passwordInput);
            }();

            Login.submitLoginRequest = function () { 
                var u = new InputUtil();
                var e = new LoginErrors();

                var userName = document.getElementById(Login.userNameInput);
                var password = document.getElementById(Login.passwordInput);

                if (!userName.value || !userName.value.match('[@\\\\]')) {
                    u.setError(userName, e.userNameFormatError);
                    return false;
                }

                if (!password.value) {
                    u.setError(password, e.passwordEmpty);
                    return false;
                }

                if (password.value.length > maxPasswordLength) {
                    u.setError(password, e.passwordTooLong);
                    return false;
                }

                document.forms['loginForm'].submit();
                return false;
            };

            InputUtil.makePlaceholder(Login.userNameInput);
            InputUtil.makePlaceholder(Login.passwordInput);
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>

    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="footerPlaceholder"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footerLinks" class="floatReverse">
                     <div><span id="copyright">&#169; 2013 Microsoft</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

// This file contains several workarounds on inconsistent browser behaviors that administrators may customize.
"use strict";

// iPhone email friendly keyboard does not include "\" key, use regular keyboard instead.
// Note change input type does not work on all versions of all browsers.
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) {
    var emails = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='email']");
    if (emails) {
        for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
            emails[i].type = 'text';
        }
    }
}

// In the CSS file we set the ms-viewport to be consistent with the device dimensions, 
// which is necessary for correct functionality of immersive IE. 
// However, for Windows 8 phone we need to reset the ms-viewport's dimension to its original
// values (auto), otherwise the viewport dimensions will be wrong for Windows 8 phone.
// Windows 8 phone has agent string 'IEMobile 10.0'
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
        )
    );
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{height:auto!important}"
        )
    );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}

// If the innerWidth is defined, use it as the viewport width.
if (window.innerWidth && window.outerWidth && window.innerWidth !== window.outerWidth) {
    var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=' + window.innerWidth + 'px; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0');
}

// Gets the current style of a specific property for a specific element.
function getStyle(element, styleProp) {
    var propStyle = null;

    if (element && element.currentStyle) {
        propStyle = element.currentStyle[styleProp];
    }
    else if (element && window.getComputedStyle) {
        propStyle = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    }

    return propStyle;
}

// The script below is used for downloading the illustration image 
// only when the branding is displaying. This script work together
// with the code in PageBase.cs that sets the html inline style
// containing the class 'illustrationClass' with the background image.
var computeLoadIllustration = function () {
    var branding = document.getElementById("branding");
    var brandingDisplay = getStyle(branding, "display");
    var brandingWrapperDisplay = getStyle(document.getElementById("brandingWrapper"), "display");

    if (brandingDisplay && brandingDisplay !== "none" &&
        brandingWrapperDisplay && brandingWrapperDisplay !== "none") {
        var newClass = "illustrationClass";

        if (branding.classList && branding.classList.add) {
            branding.classList.add(newClass);
        } else if (branding.className !== undefined) {
            branding.className += " " + newClass;
        }
        if (window.removeEventListener) {
            window.removeEventListener('load', computeLoadIllustration, false);
            window.removeEventListener('resize', computeLoadIllustration, false);
        }
        else if (window.detachEvent) {
            window.detachEvent('onload', computeLoadIllustration);
            window.detachEvent('onresize', computeLoadIllustration);
        }
    }
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', computeLoadIllustration, false);
    window.addEventListener('load', computeLoadIllustration, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', computeLoadIllustration);
    window.attachEvent('onload', computeLoadIllustration);
}

// Check whether the userNameInput element is present on this page.
var userNameInput = document.getElementById('userNameInput');
if (userNameInput)
{
// userNameInput element is present, modify its properties.
userNameInput.placeholder = 'domain\\userid';
}
//]]>
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Edit

Web.config for web api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyWebAPIsample-20180828043416.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyWebAPIsample-20180828043416;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://devadfs/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml"/>
    <add key="ida:Realm" value="https://mywebapi/"/>
    <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://mywebapi/"/>
  </appSettings>
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://mywebapi/"/>
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"/>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="http://devadfs/adfs/services/trust">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="1EBF4FB5B1248012B10248012B9B2CEE407D0CC8"/>
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://devadfs/adfs/services/trust"/>
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="true"/>
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://devadfs/adfs/ls/" realm="https://mywebapi/" requireHttps="true"/>
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working also desktop application. I have also api call. Calling api from my desktop client by SendRequest method like

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequest(HttpMethod method, string endPoint, string accessToken,  dynamic content = null)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, endPoint))
                {
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                    if (content != null)
                    {
                        string c;
                        if (content is string)
                            c = content;
                        else
                            c = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                        request.Content = new StringContent(c, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    }

                    response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            return response;

        }
```

And it's working fine. You can try with this.

Also change your return like

```
[Route("Test")]
    public ActionResult GetTestData()
    {
        return Ok(new { value1="value1",value2="value2" });
    }
```

Comment: That didn't work.  It's still resulting in the text/html document.  I wonder if it's an issue with the web api's web config.

Comment: I tried making those changes as well and I'm still having the same issue.  Did you have to make any changes to the Web.config for the Web Api?  I used Visual Studio and it automatically modified the Web.config.